# Передача данных из datagridview из разных форм

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

На 3 формах есть 3 датагрида, по одному на каждой. На 1 и 2 таблице в датагриде есть значения. На 3 форме есть датагрид и кнопка. Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку а датагрид на 3 форме записывались значения из датагридов 1 и 2 формы?

Comment: как формы связаны между собой? интересует связь родитель-потомок, или если проще порядок открытия форм и инициаторы открытия. Какой источник данных используется для 1-го и 2-го гридов?

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое передать в 3 форму указатели на первые 2 датагрида. Можно их сделать `public` в формах, и передать формы и достучаться через `Form.DataGridView`.
Ну а дальше выбирать данные по ячейкам и копировать.

Чуть более, возможно, правильнее добавить в форму метод доступа к ячейки датагрида, его можно сделать константным чтобы защитить первые 2 датагрида. И передать этот метод в 3 форму для доступа.